# Mapping signed integer ranges to unsigned

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, int

I'm facing a problem where signed integers should be converted to unsigneds, preserving their range and order.

Given the following definition:

```
#include <limits>

#define MIN(X) std::numeric_limits<X>::min();
#define MAX(X) std::numeric_limits<X>::max();
```

What is the fastest and correct way to map the signed range **[MIN(T), MAX(T)]** to the unsigned range **[0, MAX(U)]**?

where:

> **T is a signed integer type**
>
> **U is an unsigned integer type**
>
> **sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)**

I tried various bit twiddling and numeric methods to come up with a solution, without success.

Comment: _"I'm facing a problem where signed integers should be converted to unsigneds, preserving their range"_ Er, what did you expect `-1` to become? Are you trying to preserve the range but not the actual value? Or what? And _what_ "various methods" didn't work for you? In what way did they not work? (what is "without success" in this context?) Ask a specific question about a specific approach.

Comment: Well if you preserve the range, you preserve the value, since a value is defined by it's position inside the range. If you read the question it is clearly about range conversion, where -MAX(T) becomes 0. So -1 becomes MAX(U)/2 - 1.

Comment: @plasmacel I suggest editing your question to clarify the intention in your last comment.  In general, mapping ABC to XYZ would be satisfied by A->X, B->Z, C->Y for example.

Comment: You appear to also be assuming two's complement representation (otherwise the ranges will not be of equal size)

Comment: why don't just cast to unsigned? The bit pattern will always be preserved

Comment: inverse at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123682/c-mapping-unsigned-integer-ranges-to-signed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
unsigned int signedToUnsigned(signed int s) {
  unsigned int u =  1U + std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  u += s;
  return u;
}
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/WLOnbs)

This will add `signed_max + 1` to `signed int` to ensure `[MIN(int), MAX(int)]` is mapped to `[0, MAX(unsigned int)]`

---

**Why would this answer work and map correctly:**

When you add a signed integral number to an unsigned, the signed number is promoted to unsigned type. From Section 4.7 [conv.integral]

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least
>   unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>   where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [
>   Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is
>   conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no
>   truncation). —end note ]

Comment: Excellent explanation with quoted standard.

Comment: Indeed, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @plasmacel as your question specified arbitrary integral types, I'll leave it as simply saying it is also possible to do this as a generic template with proper use of `std:::make_unsigned` and a little creative SFINAE.

Comment: More precisely, `[conv.prom]` says both the `int` and the `unsigned int` get promoted to `long` (assuming that's longer than `int`) to do the addition, and then the result gets converted back to `unsigned int` using the rule from `[conv.integral]`. (or... does `+=` work differently from `+`?)